# MomentJS comparing Unix time with minutes and get difference

Tags: momentjs

I need to find if currentDate time (unix) and lastFetchedTime(unix) is greater than 30 minutes in moment.js.

How can compare the subtracted value from 30 minutes in moment?

`lastFetchedTime(unix)` is equivalent to the previous Date.now()..

```js
const now = moment(Date.now());

const lastFetched = 1598578706;
const checkTime = now.diff(lastFetched, 'minutes') > 30 ;
```

Comment: How is `lastFetchedTime` looks like ?

Comment: lastFetchedTime is also unix time . e.g  If current time is 10:00AM (unix )last time should be 9:30 AM(unix)

Comment: Would you mind [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) below if i have provided a working solution to your question. Thanks

Comment: This is the answer that I needed really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks and happy coding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **momentJS** [duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) function to get the difference between two times which are in `unix` format.

Firstly, you need to convert the `unix` format to human `readable` time and then get the [difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) of `current` time and `lastFetched` time using [asMinutes](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) function of duration

If the difference is greater then `30` then do something `else` or do something `else`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
const now = moment().unix()
const lastFetched = 1598597404; 
const duration = moment.duration(moment.unix(now).diff(moment.unix(lastFetched)));
const getMinutes = duration.asMinutes();

if (getMinutes > 30) {
  console.log('Minutes are GREATER then 30 minutes - from now')
} else {
  console.log('Minutes are LESS then 30 minutes - from now')
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.js"></script>
```